# Showing Error in Android Sqlite database sync on internet connection available

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am working on an android app where I need to sync my local SQLite database to MySql database on internet available.
step 1: When the app runs with internet connection,data will be sent to real server.
step 2: When the app runs without internet connection,data will be stored in local sqlite database.When app gets internet,stored data will be synced to real server database.

In my app ,step 1 is working fine.But when data tried to be synced, app is being crushed.

I am providing below my error log and classes.

```
[ERROR] FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.w3xplorers.syncdb, PID: 3357
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.w3xplorers.syncdb/databases/sqlite_db
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1522)
                                                                     at com.w3xplorers.syncdb.DBHelper.updateDatabase(DBHelper.java:52)
                                                                     at com.w3xplorers.syncdb.NetworkMonitor$1.onResponse(NetworkMonitor.java:48)
                                                                     at com.w3xplorers.syncdb.NetworkMonitor$1.onResponse(NetworkMonitor.java:41)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Dbhelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + DBContact.TABLE_NAME+
        " (id integer primary key autoincrement,"+DBContact.NAME+" text,"+DBContact.STATUS+" integer);";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "drop table if exists "+DBContact.TABLE_NAME;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBContact.DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void saveToLocalDatabase(String name,int sync_status,SQLiteDatabase database){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DBContact.NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(DBContact.STATUS,sync_status);
    database.insert(DBContact.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

}

public Cursor readFromLocalDb(SQLiteDatabase database){
    String[] projections = {DBContact.NAME,DBContact.STATUS};
    return (database.query(DBContact.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null));
}

public void updateDatabase(String name,int sync_status,SQLiteDatabase database){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DBContact.STATUS,sync_status);
    String selection = DBContact.NAME+" Like ?";
    String[] selection_args = {name};
    database.update(DBContact.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,selection,selection_args);
}
}
```

NetworkMonitor.java

```
public class NetworkMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(checkNetworkConnection(context)){
        final DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDb(database);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.STATUS));
            if(sync_status==DBContact.sync_status_failed){
                final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContact.NAME));
                StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DBContact.SERVER_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String s) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                                    String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                                    if(Response.equals("OK")){
                                        dbHelper.updateDatabase(name,DBContact.sync_status_ok,database);
                                        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DBContact.UI_UPDATE_BROADCAST));
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                })
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String ,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("name",name);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        }

        dbHelper.close();
    }
}

public boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem is in your **NetworkMonitor** class in **onReceive** end statement
you closing database

```
dbHelper.close();
```

but in **onResponse** u accessing same **dbHelper** so you have to remove  **dbHelper.close();** and close it in **onResponse**

Better u create your **SQLiteDatabase** instance in  DBHelper  class functions where u want to use it to avoid such problems

Comment: (DBHelper.java:52) database.update(DBContact.TABLE_NAME,contentValues,selection,selection_args);

(NetworkMonitor.java:48)
dbHelper.updateDatabase(name,DBContact.sync_status_ok,database);

Comment: what is the problem now ur getting?

Comment: do one thing before calling dbHelper.updateDatabase create new dbHelper object and check

Comment: It is working now.But what is the problem with dbhelper object?

Comment: want to suggest why not u creating SQLiteDatabase instance  in SqlitHelper class it will be better approach to create there, in your case SQLiteDatabase   object may be closed after your first operation so u have to invoke  dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145299/discussion-between-pavan-and-avijit).